# How to get the contents of a HTML element

Tags: go

I'm quite new to Go and I'm struggling a little at the moment with parsing some html.

The HTML looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>something</div>

    <div id="publication">
        <div>I want <span>this</span></div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>not this</div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And I want to get this as a string:

```
<div>I want <span>this</span></div>
```

I've tried html.NewTokenizer() (from golang.org/x/net/html) but can't seem to get the entire contents of an element back from a token or node. I've also tried using depth with this but it picked up other bits of code.

I've also had a go with goquery which seems perfect, code:

```
doc, err := goquery.NewDocument("{url}")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

doc.Find("#publication").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
    fmt.Printf("Review %d: %s\n", i, s.Html())
})
```

But s.Text() will only print out the text and s.Html() doesn't seem to exist (?).

I think parsing it as XML would work, except the actual HTML is very deep and there would have to be a struct for each parent element...

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: What do you mean "Html()" doesn't seem to exist? https://godoc.org/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#Selection.Html -- It returns 2 values, so your code can't compile.

Comment: ahhh ha! of course, that looks way better! - thanks @JimB :) seems to work now. For the record, changed it to: 
`html, _ := s.Html()`
`fmt.Printf("Review %d: %s\n", i, html)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not getting the result (s.Html() actually exist), because you haven't set the variable and error handler.

Please add this to your code and it will work fine:

```
doc.Find("#publication").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
    inside_html,_ := s.Html() //underscore is an error
    fmt.Printf("Review %d: %s\n", i, inside_html)
})
```